# Parent Route Not Asked to Handle Event?

Tags: ember.js

[The guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/) says that when an action is triggered, Ember first looks for a handler in the current controller, then if it can't find it in the controller it looks in the current route, then the parent route, etc. I'm not seeing that happen.

My routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    // Creates 'products' and 'products.index' routes
    this.resource('products', function(){
        // ...
    });
});
```

My super trivial *products.index* template;

```
<span {{action fooBar}}>Run fooBar</span>
```

To test this, I'm currently at */#/products in the browser*, and Ember logs *"Transitioned into 'products.index'"* saying I'm currently in the products.index route, as I expect. Now if click on the action, Ember should look for a handler in:

1. ProductsIndexController
2. ProductsIndexRoute
3. ProductsRoute

My observations:

- If I put the handler in ProductsIndexController, it works.
- If I put the handler in ProductsIndexRoute, it works.
- However, if I put the handler in ProductsRoute, it's never called:

.

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
        fooBar: function(){
            alert("alarm!");
        }
    }
});
```

Instead I see the error:

```
*Error: Nothing handled the event 'fooBar'.*
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces this behaviour and perhaps open an [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my other javascript files was also setting/creating App.ProductsRoute (and doing nothing with it), which was causing a conflict. Silly mistake.